Webpage display across different screen types
I'm trying to make a webpage uniform across all screen types, here is a snippet of the code, this is the header...
style.css
@import url('https:fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap');

*       {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        }
 
body    {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
        }


/* Header Styles */
header {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 30px 100px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: #333;
        color: #fff;
        }
 
header .logo
       {
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: 700;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 2em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        }
 
header ul {
        display: flex;
        justify-content:center;
        align-items: center;
          }
 
header ul li {
        list-style: none;
        margin-right: 20px;
          }
 
header ul li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 6px 15px;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 20px;
          } 
 
header ul li a:hover {
        background: #fff;
        color:#333;
          }

'''
'''
<header>
  <a href="#" class="logo">LOGO</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="search.html">Search</a></li>
    <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>

'''
A responsive design code was put in, but it doesn't seem to work perfectly... The different elements have been edited but did not seem to have a perfect result once the screen was reduced. It would be nice to get a review and help on this

"but it doesn't seem to work perfectly [...] did not seem to have a perfect result" - Can you be more specific about the problem you are observing and the question you are asking?

@David Im trying to make the code uniform across all screen types. On a pc, it works perfectly fine and shows the proper code how its supposed to be displayed. But when you load it on a mobile or reduce the screen from a full screen it looks different

After looking closely at the code, I found a few problems. First, you've used position: fixed; way too much, which is generally not good for responsive web design. Second, you used repeated code inside media query. For responsive design, you should only use updated properties inside media query, and you don't need to use the entire code, not just the updated properties. I provide updated code for it. Hope it helps you.


/* Global Styles */
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

/* Header Styles */
header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 30px 100px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    gap: 40px;
}

header .logo {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

header ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

header ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

header ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 6px 15px;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

header ul li a:hover {
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
}


/* Responsive Design */
/* Mobile Devices (480px and below) */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    
    header {
        padding: 25px 30px;
        gap: 16px;
    }
}

/* Tablets and Small Laptops (481px to 768px) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    header {
        padding: 25px 75px;
        gap: 32px;
    } 
}
<header>
    <a href="#" class="logo">LOGO</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="search.html">Search</a></li>
        <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>




It does, to some extent, would your code be responsive on all screen types?

Yes, of course, I tested my code on all screen resolution and it works very well.

forgive me, that styling is not the original of the problem, but rather an unfinished solution. Here is the original header layout...
